# How can I manually set an Angular form field as invalid?

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I am working on a login form and if the user enters invalid credentials we want to mark both the email and password fields as invalid and display a message that says the login failed. How do I go about setting these fields to be invalid from an observable callback?

Template:

```html
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)" id="loginForm">
  <div class="login-content" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" required [(ngModel)]="password">
    </md-input-container>
    <p class='error' *ngIf='loginFailed'>The email address or password is invalid.</p>
    <div class="extra-options" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
     <md-checkbox class="remember-me">Remember Me</md-checkbox>
      <a class="forgot-password" routerLink='/forgot-password'>Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
    <button class="login-button" md-raised-button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">SIGN IN</button>
     <p class="note">Don't have an account?<br/> <a [routerLink]="['/register']">Click here to create one</a></p>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Login method:

```ts
 @ViewChild('loginForm') loginForm: HTMLFormElement;

 private login(formData: any): void {
    this.authService.login(formData).subscribe(res => {
      alert(`Congrats, you have logged in. We don't have anywhere to send you right now though, but congrats regardless!`);
    }, error => {
      this.loginFailed = true; // This displays the error message, I don't really like this, but that's another issue.
      this.loginForm.controls.email.invalid = true;
      this.loginForm.controls.password.invalid = true; 
    });
  }
```

In addition to setting the inputs invalid flag to true I've tried setting the `email.valid` flag to false, and setting the `loginForm.invalid` to true as well. None of these cause the inputs to display their invalid state.

Comment: Is your backend on a different port than angular? If so this might be a CORS issue. What framework are you using for the backend.

Comment: You can use `setErros` method. Tips: You should add the required validator on your component file. Also is there a specific reason to use ngModel with reactive forms?

Comment: @developer033 a little late to the party here, but those do not look like Reactive Form, but a Template-driven form.

Answer (score 461, accepted):

in component:

```javascript
formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

and in HTML:

```html
<input mdInput placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email"  #email="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="!email.valid">{{email.errors| json}}</div>
```

Comment: And how do you remove the error afterward ? `setErrors({'incorrect': false})` or `setErrrors({})` are not working for me

Comment: Can I set a whole reactive form as valid or invalid instead of resetting fields?

Comment: @Robouste you can remove the errors manually by `setErrrors(null)`

Comment: In addition to this answer: this code doesn't work for me without `formData.form.controls['email'].markAsTouched();` as @M.Farahmand mentioned below. Using `setErrors({'incorrect': true})` just set `ng-invalid` css class for input. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: What about reactive forms?

Comment: The same statement seems to work for Reactive forms as well.

Comment: @xtremist - To set it at the form level try `formData.form.setErrors({'incorrect': true});`

Comment: Make sure not to run `control.updateValueAndValidity()` afterward, as I did. It will wipe out the error.

Comment: And what if there are more validators, like "required" - does setErrors(null) delete that error?

Comment: FYI `setErrors(null)` isn't allowed when using TypeScript with strict null checks.

Comment: How can I preserve setError after updateValueAndValidity() call ?

Comment: @NaN you could use the spread operator like this `control.setErrors({ ...control.errors, incorrect: true })` to add something new and keep the existing. Note that if it already had incorrect on it, this would overwrite that.

Comment: Also, if you run setErrors(null) it removes all errors, but you can just run control.updateValueAndValidity() and it will re-add any errors from validators to get it back to its not-manually-messed-with-state

Answer (score 156):

Adding to Julia Passynkova's answer

To set validation error in component:

```javascript
formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

To unset validation error in component:

```javascript
formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors(null);
```

Be careful with unsetting the errors using `null` as this will overwrite all errors. If you want to keep some around you may have to check for the existence of other errors first:

```javascript
if (isIncorrectOnlyError){
   formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors(null);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to unset validation error using something like formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors({'incorrect': false});

Comment: What about reactive forms?

Comment: the whole code that' mentioned in the answer is a full example of reactive forms my dear

Comment: "Be careful with unsetting the errors using null as this will overwrite all errors." Yes, that would be my question how to remove just that one error and let the others stay there.

Comment: no you cannot set false because angular check if any error not by the value. i think its for the user to display error or not. 
  private _calculateStatus(): FormControlStatus {
    if (this._allControlsDisabled()) return DISABLED;
    if (this.errors) return INVALID;
    if (this._hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator || this._anyControlsHaveStatus(PENDING)) return PENDING;
    if (this._anyControlsHaveStatus(INVALID)) return INVALID;
    return VALID;
  }

but you can just set false and display no error when false

Comment: This response is a lifesaver. Thank you. I first tried the control method suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887417/15012852. It worked, but angular 14 says it's depreciated to use it alongside ngModel.
About the concerns of overwriting all errors with null expressed in the comments, you can just do a javascript check for all the error object keys and values. If all have been met, then set errors to null. That could be one way to do it.

Comment: Continued: If all the others have not been met and setting errors to null will make things complicated, then just remove the property you are dealing with from the error object and setErrors to the modified object.

Answer (score 47):

In new version of material 2 which its control name starts with mat prefix setErrors() doesn't work, instead Juila's answer can be changed to:

```
formData.form.controls['email'].markAsTouched();
```

Comment: mark as touched doesnt make a control invalid

Comment: @sudharsantk It's true that it doesn't make a control invalid however this code does correct a problem where an invalid field is not reported as invalid.  For example, the above mentioned code is required after you programmatically set a required field to blank.

Answer (score 41):

I was trying to call `setErrors()` inside a ngModelChange handler in a template form.  It did not work until I waited one tick with `setTimeout()`:

template:

```html
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="form-control" 
 id="password" name="password" required (ngModelChange)="checkPasswords()">

<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="pwConfirm" class="form-control"
 id="pwConfirm" name="pwConfirm" required (ngModelChange)="checkPasswords()"
 #pwConfirmModel="ngModel">

<div [hidden]="pwConfirmModel.valid || pwConfirmModel.pristine" class="alert-danger">
   Passwords do not match
</div>
```

component:

```js
@ViewChild('pwConfirmModel') pwConfirmModel: NgModel;

checkPasswords() {
  if (this.pwConfirm.length >= this.user.password.length &&
      this.pwConfirm !== this.user.password) {
    console.log('passwords do not match');
    // setErrors() must be called after change detection runs
    setTimeout(() => this.pwConfirmModel.control.setErrors({'nomatch': true}) );
  } else {
    // to clear the error, we don't have to wait
    this.pwConfirmModel.control.setErrors(null);
  }
}
```

Gotchas like this are making me prefer reactive forms.

Comment: `Cannot find name 'NgModel'.` error for line `@ViewChild('pwConfirmModel') pwConfirmModel: NgModel;` any fix for this issue

Comment: What is up with having to use setTimeOuts?  I have noticed this as well as it appears controls don't immediately update themselves.  This introduces a lot of hacky code to work around this limitation.

Comment: Thanks. I knew `setErrors` but it didn't work till I used `setTimeout`

Comment: I would suggest to use timer() operator instead of timeout

Comment: After using setError what I would advice doing is using the `updateValueAndValidity()` method

Answer (score 14):

In my Reactive form, I needed to mark a field as invalid if another field was checked. In ng version 7 I did the following:

```
    const checkboxField = this.form.get('<name of field>');
    const dropDownField = this.form.get('<name of field>');

    this.checkboxField$ = checkboxField.valueChanges
        .subscribe((checked: boolean) => {
            if(checked) {
                dropDownField.setValidators(Validators.required);
                dropDownField.setErrors({ required: true });
                dropDownField.markAsDirty();
            } else {
                dropDownField.clearValidators();
                dropDownField.markAsPristine();
            }
        });
```

So above, when I check the box it sets the dropdown as required and marks it as dirty. If you don't mark as such it then it won't be invalid (in error) until you try to submit the form or interact with it.

If the checkbox is set to false (unchecked) then we clear the required validator on the dropdown and reset it to a pristine state.

Also - remember to unsubscribe from monitoring field changes!

Comment: markAsDirty() is the key

Answer (score 13):

You could also change the viewChild 'type' to NgForm as in:

```
@ViewChild('loginForm') loginForm: NgForm;
```

And then reference your controls in the same way @Julia mentioned:

```
 private login(formData: any): void {
    this.authService.login(formData).subscribe(res => {
      alert(`Congrats, you have logged in. We don't have anywhere to send you right now though, but congrats regardless!`);
    }, error => {
      this.loginFailed = true; // This displays the error message, I don't really like this, but that's another issue.

      this.loginForm.controls['email'].setErrors({ 'incorrect': true});
      this.loginForm.controls['password'].setErrors({ 'incorrect': true});
    });
  }
```

Setting the Errors to null will clear out the errors on the UI:

```
this.loginForm.controls['email'].setErrors(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that works:

```
MatchPassword(AC: FormControl) {
  let dataForm = AC.parent;
  if(!dataForm) return null;

  var newPasswordRepeat = dataForm.get('newPasswordRepeat');
  let password = dataForm.get('newPassword').value;
  let confirmPassword = newPasswordRepeat.value;

  if(password != confirmPassword) {
    /* for newPasswordRepeat from current field "newPassword" */
    dataForm.controls["newPasswordRepeat"].setErrors( {MatchPassword: true} );
    if( newPasswordRepeat == AC ) {
      /* for current field "newPasswordRepeat" */
      return {newPasswordRepeat: {MatchPassword: true} };
    }
  } else {
    dataForm.controls["newPasswordRepeat"].setErrors( null );
  }
  return null;
}

createForm() {
  this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
    password: [ "", Validators.required ],
    newPassword: [ "", [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), this.MatchPassword] ],
    newPasswordRepeat: [ "", [Validators.required, this.MatchPassword] ]
  });
}
```

Comment: This might be "hacky", but I like it because you don't have to set a custom ErrorStateMatcher to work with Angular Material Input errors!

Answer (score 2):

Though its late but following solution worked form me.

```
    let control = this.registerForm.controls['controlName'];
    control.setErrors({backend: {someProp: "Invalid Data"}});
    let message = control.errors['backend'].someProp;
```

Comment: This worked great! Just updated my form-error component to handle custom `backend.message` string accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to set and clear a custom error without clearing others.

Setting it:

```
this.form.controls['email'].setErrors({ 'custom': true });
```

Clearing it:

```
const errors = this.form.controls['email'].errors;
        if (errors) {
          errors['custom'] = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) in Angular documentation might help:
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"

```
      required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
      [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel">

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
    class="alert">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.['required']">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.['minlength']">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.['forbiddenName']">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>

</div>
```