# set form manually to invalid angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Is there a way to set a formGroup to invalid state manually?

I tried `myForm.invalid = true;` and also `myForm.status = 'INVALID'`

But `invalid` and `status` are `const`.

I dont want to mark a specific control as invalid. But the whole form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Forms Manually Mark invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/angular-2-forms-manually-mark-invalid)

Comment: no it's not. I dont want to mark a specific control as invalid. But the whole form.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this:

```
myForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
```

Comment: Worked for me. To make it valid I also did myForm.setErrors(null)

Comment: Fyi... You can also use setErrors the same way on a specific form element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
`formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});`