# How to set particular validation to false in angular 2?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular2-forms

Suppose I set one custom validation to true on particular condition like this

```
if(condition){
this.form.contains['field'].setErrors({myValidation : true});
}
```

Then after some time I need to reset that particular validation **(Not entire control validation)** to false like

```
this.form.contains['field'].setErrors({myValidation : false});
```

It is not working. Here the only option is to set

```
this.form.contains['field'].setErrors(null);
```

But this sets all validation of the particular control to false.

How to set the particular validation of the control in the form to false?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Forms Manually Mark invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/angular-2-forms-manually-mark-invalid)

Comment: Did you try : `this.form.contains['field'].setErrors({myValidation : null});`

Comment: It is not that duplicate. There they are suggesting to set all validations to null. But I'm asking how to set particular validation to null. @Husein

Comment: Yes. Tried. It also makes the validation like True setting only. When we are entering some validation name inside .setErrors() it makes the validation 'true' without considering the option what we are giving. @Nishad