# Validation from reactive forms doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, forms, typescript, angular5

I've got a problem with my reactive forms - my repeatPassword doesn't refresh. If I write something in "password" label, then in "repeatPassword" and again in "password" the second one is not marked as invalid.

So I decided to do something like that:

```
if (this.form.get('password').value !== this.form.get('passwordRepeat').value) {
  this.form.get('passwordRepeat').setErrors({'invalid': true});
}

if (this.form.get('password').value === this.form.get('passwordRepeat').value &&
  !this.form.get('passwordRepeat').hasError) {
  this.form.get('passwordRepeat').setErrors({'invalid': null});
}
```

The code looks fine until I try to set invalid to null - reactive forms treat it like an error, so I can't submit and ngif shows an error.

The same error occurs when I'm trying to accept rules - unchecking checkbox doesn't mark it as invalid.

Is there any option that forces validators to run once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting 
`this.form.get('passwordRepeat').setErrors(null);` 
instead of 
`this.form.get('passwordRepeat').setErrors({'invalid': null});`?

Also `this.form.get('passwordRepeat').setErrors({'invalid': false});` should work properly.

[See this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369930/3664014) that explains how to set validation errors in component.