# Why mat-error not get displayed inside mat-form field in angular material 6 withcustom global validators

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6, angular-material-6

i am using angular material 6 ,i have a vaidation inside mat-form-field mat-error is not displayed , when move after mat-form-field to the mat-error which is displaying properly.

Not Working code:

```
 <mat-form-field>
<input matInput type="time" formControlName="ToTime"/> <mat-error *ngIf="DaterForm.get('ToTime').hasError('InValidToTime')">FromTime Should be less than ToTime if choose a same date</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>
```

Working Fine:

```
 <input matInput type="time" formControlName="ToTime"/> </mat-form-field>
 <mat-error *ngIf="DaterForm.get('ToTime').hasError('InValidToTime')">FromTime Should be less than ToTime if choose a same date</mat-error>
```

Some one explain why which is not working inside that control.

Live Demo:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-dhcmd4?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, `mat-error` does not show up by default. It only shows when the input is `touched`.

But, luckily you can override this behavior using `errorStateMatcher` input property, bound to `mat-input` element.

The [pull request](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/4750/files) in which this feature was added.

Usage :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a Start date" 
    formControlName="FromDate"
      [min]="minFromDate" 
           [max]="maxToDate" >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error >Please provide a valid Fromdate</mat-error> 
  </mat-form-field>
```

So you have to implement `ErrorStateMatcher` in your code this way.

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return (control && control.invalid);
  }
}
```

And in your component add a new object `matcher` for `ErrorStateMatcher` class, which will act as a value to `[errorStateMatcher]="matcher"`

```
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

I have also added the same code in your forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-ypcmpx?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)

**Suggestion** :

You need not provide a `ngIf` condition for `mat-error` specifying your `formControlName`. It will be automatically considered based on the `mat-form-field` in which it is present.

Comment: thanks for the valuable suggestion,Is there any other way to do the same behaviour ?But in your solution your have removed the NgIf directive in mat error , i don't want to display a error message by default when form gets touched which not met the particular condition need to show the error message ,eg)`<input matInput   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" type="time" formControlName="ToTime" > <mat-error *ngIf="DaterForm.get('ToTime').hasError('InValidToTime')">FromTime Should be less than ToTime if choose a same date</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>`

Comment: You have nothing specific in `*ngIf`. You are doing the same thing what `mat-error` will do. It is redundant. And If you dont want to display error before it is touched, thats what `mat-error` does by default.

Comment: ok got it i have removed the `*ngIF` and tried this  with errorstateMatcher and Without ErrorstateMatcher then why which is not working `To Time:
 <mat-form-field>
<input matInput [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"   type="time" formControlName="ToTime" > 
<mat-error >FromTime Should be less than ToTime if choose a same date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>`.  here is a forked :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator-gbcjep?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: That is probably because you have not mentioned your time `Validators` against your `toTime` form control as a part of `formGroup`. `mat-error` will not get to know the global `Validators`. You should specify the `Validators` clearly against each formControl if you expect them to be shown by `mat-error`

Comment: `*ngIf="DaterForm.get('ToTime').hasError('InValidToTime')"` will never be true, because your error is never bound to `ToTime` form control.

Comment: You can try adding errors manually to your form control https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/how-can-i-manually-set-an-angular-form-field-as-invalid

Comment: I am looking for this as per your answer mat error does not know the global validators, and already get the error message when provide the validators against particular control , if i do that i am getting particular control values , therefore i have written the global validators after that i have get this problem is there any other better way to do this ?, i need all the formcontrol values in particular To time controlchanges l, therefore i have written the global validators but which is not shows the error there ,  thanks for the valuable comments.I will update my question

Comment: You can modify that as a custom Validator against toTime formControl as opposed to global Validator.

Comment: ErrorStateMatcher is exactly what I was looking for. My UI designer didn't want the error state to appear when the form was still pristine. Happens when you just focus, don't add input and remove focus. Using this I can only show error state if the form control is not pristine anymore. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I Found a very simple solution without overriding the ErrorStateMatcher Class, simply you could import in the app.module.ts

1- Import libraries:

```
import { ErrorStateMatcher, ShowOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
```

2- Add to providers like:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService,
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: ShowOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher }
  ],
})
```

Re-Serve the app.

Updated on 1/2/2021 by [Reza Taba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944285/reza-taba)

**There is an issue with the above short solution though:** If the user leaves the field blank after being touched (blur), the **required** error is not shown.

See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65542049/3944285) for the fix.

Comment: Not true. Dirty is the opposite of pristine. `get dirty(): boolean { return !this.pristine; }`  Touched is just whether it has had focus (tabbed through or using mouse/touch). And something can become dirty programatically without ever being touched.

Comment: The source here is useful to make sure your assumptions are correct. Yes it can be confusing! https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1b0b36d14322a77e67a106991174db36b1c8bcd7/packages/forms/src/model.ts

Comment: While what sherif proposed is true, for lazy loaded modules this doesn't work. There is an open issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10084

Answer (score 1):

**Globally, Show mat-error while typing or touched**:
Unlike the provided solution, this method will take care of all mat-errors without the need of applying a matcher to each input field.

1- Create **touched-error-state.matcher.ts** file:

```
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class TouchedErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
    }
}
```

2- In **app.module** import:

```
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { TouchedErrorStateMatcher } from './your-folder-path/touched-error-state.matcher';
```

3- Now provide it into the providers:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService,
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: TouchedErrorStateMatcher }
  ],
})
```

4- Re-Serve the app.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add The Below Function :

```
validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
        const control = formGroup.get(field);
        if (control instanceof FormControl) {
            control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
        } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
            this.validateAllFormFields(control);
        }
    });
}
```

And call It in ngOnInit function with your FormGroup , Like Below :

```
    this.validateAllFormFields(this.submittedForm);
```