# How to avoid mat-form-field Validation trigger when matInput lose focus?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have the following FormGroup in createGroup.component.ts

```
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  groupName: new FormControl({ value: this.data.groupName, disabled: this.isEditPopup }, [
    Validators.required
  ]),
  groupDescription: new FormControl(this.data.groupDescription, [
  ]),
  groupId: new FormControl(this.data.groupId, [
  ])
});
```

I have the below angular html that uses material directives in createGroup.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="groupName" placeholder="Group name*">
        </mat-form-field>`enter code here`
        <div *ngIf="(formGroup.controls['groupName'].touched)">
            <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls['groupName'].hasError('required') ">
                Group Name is required
            </mat-error>
    </div>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button [ngClass]="['btn','btn-success','active']" type="submit">Ok</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="cancelDialog($event)" type="button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is, when cursor out focus the input, the formGroup validation gets triggered.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnuqR.png)

I need to trigger validation errors on mat-form-field only if the user pressed submit or the input is dirty, not when input is blur and touched.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456487/why-mat-error-not-get-displayed-inside-mat-form-field-in-angular-material-6-with/51457205#51457205). Please have a look at that. Its a little work around but very helpful.

To achieve what you want, you have to override the default behavior of `mat-error` using `errorStateMatcher` input property on input element.

So implement the following `ErrorStateMatcher` in your code

And you could modify `isErrorState()` as follows

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return (control && (control.dirty && control.invalid));  // show error only when dirty and invalid
  }
}
```

And place your `mat-error` and `input` tag inside the same `mat-form-field`

```
<mat-form-field>
     <input matInput [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" formControlName="groupName" placeholder="Group name*">
     <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls['groupName'].hasError('required')">
                Group Name is required
     </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: if yes how to do with [(ngModel)] ?