# clearvalidators not working in angular 6 form control

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript

I have two form group names like below. Sometimes one form is not shown to user. When both are shown I have no issues. And I have a button which is visible when the form is valid.

```
 <div
        *ngIf="showPersonalInfo"
        class="personalInfo"
        formGroupName="personalInfo"
      > 

 <div
        *ngIf="showFamilyInfo"
        class="familyInfo"
        formGroupName="familyInfo"
      > 

 <button
        *ngIf="InfoForm.valid"
        class="submitButton"
</button>
```

And I initialize my form using below code.

```
this.InfoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  personalInfo: this.getPersonalInfo(),
  familyInfo: this.getFamilyInfo(),
});
```

The code in this.getFamilyInfo() will set showFamilyInfo to true or false and it initializes the form in both the cases otherwise my html throws familyInfo is not found.

One of our service sometimes looks for the member profile and pulls existing family info/personal info and fills the model and sets showPersonalInfo/showFamilyInfo to true.

when showFamilyInfo is false my InfoForm.FamilyInfo form control is showing as invalid. To avoid this error i am clearring validators using below code but it still shows the familyInfo form control status invalid. My PersonalInfo is valid though.

How can ignore everything related to FmilyInfo when showFamilyInfo is false so the button will be visible.

```
this.InfoForm.get('familyInfo').clearValidators();
this.InfoForm.get('familyInfo').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: I am having the same issue in Angular 6. Both the following options are not working this.form.get('name').clearValidators() and this.form.controls['name'].clearValidators but for time being I have applied work around solution as per my functionality

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to clear the errors before you can update the Validity.  In the linked post, the answer by Julia P. covers how to clear the errors.  Then you run updateValueandValidity.  [How can I manually set an Angular form field as invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/how-can-i-manually-set-an-angular-form-field-as-invalid)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, in my case, the code `setErrors(null)` solved the problem.
Try to do this:

```
this.InfoForm.get('familyInfo').clearValidators();
this.InfoForm.get('familyInfo').setErrors(null); 
this.InfoForm.get('familyInfo').updateValueAndValidity();
```