# How to validate required File Upload in Angular 5 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want a user to click a button to upload a document one at a time.

Currently, when a user uploads a document, it does mark the "documents" control as satisfied. However, if the user tries to upload another document but then CANCELS, it marks the control as unsatisfied. It still has the first document, but clicking cancel on the file explorer seems to make the validator think that no document was uploaded. How can I get around this?

in my html:

```
<input type="file" formControlName="documents" (change)="uploadDocument($event.target.files)">
```

in my .ts:

```
this.formGroupName=this.formBuilder.group({
  documents: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
});
```

Right now my upoadDocument() function doesn't do anything with the validation.

Comment: I think `change` event triggers whenever a user uploads or not and cause of that your `uploadDocument` can triggers twice

Comment: So would I have to implement something inside of my uploadDocument function? Can I manipulate whether or not the required field is satisfied manually?

Comment: In your app.module.ts did you import:                                                          
>import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';                                                              and did you add FormsModule to your imports?

Comment: Yes, imports are set up correctly... I don't think this is an import issue. I'm missing logic somewhere

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed this myself. What I ended up doing was subscribing to the change event for when I attempted to upload documents, and then based on a few conditions I manually invalidated or validated the Validator.

More on this topic can be found here: [How can I manually set an Angular form field as invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/how-can-i-manually-set-an-angular-form-field-as-invalid)