# How to validate a FormControl value against a List in angular 5 reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to compare a form field's input to a List using custom validators? I am NOT trying to compare two Form Controls to each other.

I have been trying with this approach:

```
this.formGroupName = this.formBuilder.group({
    category: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.checkCategoryInput(
      this.formGroupName.get['category'].value, this.categoryList)])]
});
```

where in the `checkCategoryInput()` method I will compare the value of the 'category' form control to a list of acceptable categories.

```
public checkCategoryInput(input: string, categoryList: any[]): {[key: string]: boolean} | null{
  console.log(input);
  console.log(categoryList);
  return null;
}
```

However I am getting lost in the syntax and getting a few errors trying to do it with this approach. Does anyone have a better way to compare form control values to a list???

Comment: What errors are you getting? And where is the comparison that you are doing? Do you mean, you want to check if formcontrol value exists within a list?

Comment: Did you ever get this working @masu9?

Comment: @TR3B Hello, yes I did - however I went with a different approach. I found it easier to subscribe to the valueChanges property of the form control, and to then manually set the errors myself using .setErrors({ 'invalid': true }); for example. You can check out this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/how-can-i-manually-set-an-angular-form-field-as-invalid

Answer (score 5):

You're close, and you're right; the syntax is a bit confusing. The custom `Validator` is expected to be a `ValidatorFn` method that will be called with a parameter of `AbstractControl`. For example, here's a very basic validator:

```
public static numeric(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    return /^[0-9]+$/.test(control.value) ? null : { 'numeric': false };
}

// .. { category: [0, Validators.required, numeric] }
```

We just pass a reference of the method to the `FormBuilder`, which it will call passing the `FormControl` it's on to validate the value.

If you want to wrap up some of your own parameters with the validator, just create your own function scope and return a new method:

```
public static checkCategoryInput(input: string, categoryList: any[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        const val = control.value;
        return 'Do stuff with the value because `input` and `categoryList` are now in scope!'
    }
}
```

Just as a little extra info, since it's also not really stated well anywhere; the return signature of `{ [key: string]: boolean } | null` is what will be put on the `errors` property of the `ngControl`, so usually you return `null` if it's valid and `errorName: false` if invalid. It's something to keep in mind if you're trying to show error messages based off this particular validator.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I'm just getting one last error that I'm hoping you can assist with. I am getting the error: `Cannot read property of 'get' of undefined`. I believe this is because of how I pass my category control value into the parameter. Can you see anything wrong in my syntax there? (My first code snippet in my question)