# Angular, is there a way to "markAsTouched" a field without a Form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular2-form-validation, ignite-ui-angular

I've already know that `input` items inside a `FormControl` can be mark `dirt` or `touched` by calling any of the following methods (maybe more):  `group.markAsTouched(); form.get('control-name').markAsTouched(); form.markAllAsTouched(); form.controls[someIndex].markAsTouched();`

However, I can see that the `markAsTouched` method seems to be called when the input is `focus` and then `blur`.

**Is there a way to achieve the same result by code??** lets say, when clicked a button.

---

Here, you can see a gif of [the current standard behaviour without a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clTNm.gif), also you can test it yourself at the following live sample:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-peq11f**

To me, it seems obvious that this behaviour should be available to be triggered by code and not only when `blur` event is triggered

Something like this:

```html
<input #myInput>
<button (click)="myInput.markAsTouched()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an unique formControl `<input [formControl]="control">` and `markAsTouched`

```html
<input [formControl]="control">
<button (click)="control.markAsTouched()">click</button>
{{control.touched}}
```

Where you has in `.ts`

```js
// as a property
control = new FormControl();

// or in a function
this.control.markAsTouched();
```

A `FormControl` can belong to a `FormGroup` or not. furthermore, It's not necessary to have a tag `input`. We are using a tag input to change the value, but if you remove the `input`, the control is mark as touched too